# Sending intent with bundle using console

Tags: android, android-intent, console, bundle, adb

I'm developing an Android app listening for specific intent containing a bundle with some data. I would like to send an intent to my app using adb. I have tried with:

```
adb shell am startservice -a com.INTENT_NAME -e myBundleName myBundleData com.pkg/com.pkg.cls
```

but my app recognised it as list of string not as a bundle. Does anyone know how to send intent with bundles using am application? Unfortunately documentation says only about sending lists of string or numbers, nothing about bundle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-10.0.0_r1/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#7042) `am` has no way of accepting input data of the `bundle` type

**Update:**
In Android 7.0 the intent parameters parsing code [has been moved](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3cdb56efea044112bfe1b97b3ed78ee05e0dba46) from [Am.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-10.0.0_r1/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#7042) to [Intent.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-10.0.0_r1/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#7042) and support for more data types (like `Array[]` and `ArrayList<>` of basic types) has been added. Unfortunately there is still no support for the `Bundle` type extras in `am` command.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Do you have any idea how to send intent with bundle using console?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, trying to fake the situation where you've just installed an app after receiving a Facebook App Invite. Couldn't get the shell to work, ended up building a really simple test rig that had one button and handler code like:

```
    Button button  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trigger_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("myapp://fb-app-invite"));

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("target_url", "myapp://fb-app-invite?fromuser=673");
            intent.putExtra("al_applink_data", bundle);

            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can start it by using the following command:
adb shell am startservice -a android.intent.action.MAIN -e "key"  "value" -n com.example.test/.TestService 
Key and value should be your bundle values you want to send.
TestService should be your ServiceName 
Add  for your Service in androidmanifest.xml 
Snippet:

```
<service android:name=".TestService" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

</service>
```