# How to send byte[] intent extra value from command line?

Tags: android, adb

When I want to send an Intent with a String extra via adb shell, I can do it this way:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a <intentAction> -d <intentDataUri> -f 0x10 -es <extraName> <intentExtraString>
```

In my App, I can read it using

```
String myString = intent.getStringExtra("<extraName>");
```

There are pairs for the following types documented:

- `--es` and `getStringExtra(...)`
- `--ez` and `getBooleanExtra(...)`
- `--ei` and `getIntExtra(...)`
- `--el` and `getLongExtra(...)`
- `--ef` and `getFloatExtra(...)`
- `--eu` and **???** (Uri)
- `--ecn`and **???** (ComponentName)
- `--eia`and `getIntArrayExtra(...)`
- `--ela`and `getLongArrayExtra(...)`
- `--efa`and `getFloatArrayExtra(...)`

I need an Intent with a `byte[]` extra. I can get it with `getByteArrayExtra(...)`, but how can I set it?

I've tried `--eba`, `--eya`, `--eta` and `--eea`. Everything unknown to the program. Just using `--eia` does not work as well: Then the result of `getByteArrayExtra(...)` is `null`.

Edit: [Sending intent with bundle using console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496740/sending-intent-with-bundle-using-console) is *not* a duplicate of this question. It involves Bundles, no byte arrays.

Comment: Try passing int array and retrieve it as byte array

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about it since it was the first thing I've tried. :-D Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no option for byte array extra.

Details:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec

Do you really need to send intent by byte array? How about send it by "integer array extra", and cast it to byte?

Comment: Unfortunately not, and your link was the page I got my information from...